# Changing Style of Parent LI in Collapsible Menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu

This should be easy, but I'm having a hard time with it.

I have a simple collapsing menu that uses SPAN tags inside LI tags, the usual.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var allSpan = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
for (var i = 0; i < allSpan.length; i++) {
    allSpan[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.parentNode) {

            var childList = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('UL');

            for (var j = 0; j < childList.length; j++) {
                var currentState = childList[j].style.display;
                if (currentState == "none") {
                    childList[j].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    childList[j].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works just fine in hiding and showing the nested ULs. What I'd like to do is add a piece of code that also changes the SPAN of the clicked-on parent LI item.

I'm thinking it would be something like:

```
if(currentState=="none") {
    childList[j].style.display="block";
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
}
else {
    childList[j].style.display="none";
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing the obvious. Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

#### UPDATE

Sorry, I totally forgot there was more code at the bottom:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu').find('SPAN').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().find('UL').toggle();
    });
});
```

And here is the body of the HTML:

```
<style TYPE="text/css">
<!--
body { background: white;color: #000000;font-family:geneva; }
a:link { color: #ff8080 }
a:visited { color: #ff0000 }
a:active { color: #a05050 }

ul { margin:0;padding:0; }
li { list-style-type: none; }
ul li span { display:block;min-height:20px;background:blue;color:white;font-weight:bold;padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;border-top:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;margin:0; }

li ul { display:none; }
li ul li span { background:#98ff33;padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;color:black;font-weight:normal;display:block; }
li ul li:last-child span { border-bottom:1px solid black; }


-->
</style>


</head>
<body>

<UL id="menu">
<LI class="Category"><SPAN>Solid Tumors</SPAN><UL>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Anal Cancer</SPAN></LI>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Biliary Cancer</SPAN></LI>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Bladder Cancer</SPAN></LI>
</UL>

<LI class="Category"><SPAN>Hematologic Malignancies</SPAN><UL>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Acute Myeloid Leukemia</SPAN></LI>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Acute Promyelocytic Leukemia</SPAN></LI>

</UL>

<LI class="Category"><SPAN>Reviewers</SPAN><UL>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Physician Reviewers</SPAN></LI>

<LI class="subtopic"><SPAN>Pharmacy Reviewers </SPAN></LI>
</UL>
</UL>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the full click event, along with the HTML. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I added some missing code to the bottom.

Comment: How do I provide a fiddle?

Comment: Access http://jsfiddle.net/. Set the code, click "Save", and copy here the URL

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C6dzs/1/

At least i've learned this much! Thanks.

Comment: And what is the SPAN change that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method would be to only toggle the class of the parent li element:

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu SPAN').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

And then add then using CSS to manage the colors and the show/hide by adding the following css:

```
#menu li.open > span {
    background-color: red
}
#menu li.open ul {
    display: inline
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/3TTDJ/

Note: if you only want to do this for the first menu level and not recursive, you'll want to specify that in the selector using immediate child selector '#menu > li > SPAN':

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu > li > SPAN').click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/tleish/3TTDJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Below changes the span background color or the parent listitem

http://jsfiddle.net/tuusT/2/

```
$('#menu').find('SPAN').click(function(e){
    $('#menu').find('.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parents(".Category").children("span:first").addClass("active")
    $(this).parent().find('UL').toggle();
});
```

Comment: That's almost there. The only issue now is to change the class back to inactive when the submenu collapses on the second click.

Comment: I figured that part out after you set me up with the hard part. Also, I realized that when a submenu opened, any span in the submenu would toggle the class as well, so I added a class .clickable, and added that parameter to the function:   $('#menu').find('SPAN.clickable').click(function(e)... etc
    http://jsfiddle.net/tuusT/8/